# Request parameter is modified in my servlet

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I sent one request as URL with data to servlet, But by default servlet is modifying the data and sending as request. Can you please suggest how to maintain the request URL with data which i passed to servlet should remain same ?

Example:- when i am passing the data to servlet

> http://localhost/helloservlet/servlet/ppd.abcd.build.coupons.CouponValueFormatterServlet?dsn=frd_abc_abcde&lang=ENG&val=PRCTXT|12345 &ABCDEFG

when it using the above url in servelt as request , like string abc = request.getParameter("val"), the val attribute is trimmed automatically and assigned as " val=PRCTXT|12345" but it supposed to be like " val = PRCTXT|12345 &ABCDEFG ". Please help me on this.

Comment: `&` needs to be URL encoded. Currently you have a variable called `ABCDEFG` with no value.

Answer (score 0):

The servlet interprets each & in the URL as the start of a new parameter.  So when it sees &ABCDEFG, it thinks you are sending a new parameter called ABCDEFG with no value (though this is technically a "keyless value" according to the specifications).

Two things to fix this, first is when you want to actually send an &, use %26 instead.  This will be skipped by the code that divides up the parameters, but converted to a real & in the parameter's value.

Second is to replace spaces with +.  Spaces in URLs work sometimes but can be problematic.

So your actual request URL should look like this:

```
http://localhost/helloservlet/servlet/ppd.abcd.build.coupons.CouponValueFormatterServlet?dsn=frd_abc_abcde&lang=ENG&val=PRCTXT|12345+%26ABCDEFG
```

If you're building these parameters in javascript, you can use encodeURIComponent() to fix all problem characters for you.  So you could do something like this:

```
var userInput = *get some input here*
var addr = 'http://www.example.com?param1=' + encodeURIComponent(userInput);
```

Comment: Basically passing URL to servlet from Flex like this : coupValImg.source = "/" + Model.site.siteInfo.webContext +      "/servlet/cpd.campaign.build.coupons.CouponValueFormatterServlet?lang=" + cmpnLanguage + "&val=" + variable.value + "&width=" + variable.width + "&height=" + variable.height +     "&zoomFactor=" + zoomFactor.toString() + "&bgcolor=" + variable.bgColor + "&fgcolor=" + variable.fontColor;

Comment: in the URL,I am passing value as variable.value = "ABCDEF &12345 ", and URL is passing to servlet perfectly. But when servlet is using the value through request.getAttribute("val") is displaying only " ABCDEF" not displaying full length string which i passed as value. Please let me know , how to achieve this, even after trying encodeURLComponent(val) is also not working.

Comment: I mistyped the method name, it should be `encodeURIComponent()`.  Corrected above.  I don't know anything about Flex, but try sending the constructed URL to the browser console and see if it is fixing the `val` value.  `console.log(coupValImg.source)`